# CCK field in Workflow tab

Tags: 7, entities, workflows

I would like to add a user reference field to the Workflow tab.

Currently we have a user reference CCK field but it is only editable in the Node edit form. Really it would make much more sense to be able to "assign" the content to an owner via the Workflow Tab.

Any advice on what might be a good place to start? Existing modules / template functions etc?